# Issue with sending data over UDP using fread

Tags: c, sockets, fread

I am working on implementing a "stop and go" protocol using UDP. I essentially use a char buffer to serialize any data I send over, using ntoh and hton where needed, and deserializing once my data reaches the other side. Everything works great, however when I try to send a file, I get random bogus bytes in the new file. I will try to summarize the necessary information for this question:

The first character in my char buffer represents the type of packet that is being sent. I implemented a small 3-way handshake to establish connection. The server simply takes a specific port as an arg, the client takes an ip, port, and filename, then requests this file from the server. The server responds with the size of the file, and then the client sends the final ACK packet, then data is sent. I use fread() to send data ~1kb at a time, using a 1kb buffer size. Once the client obtains this packet, it sends a confirmation packet then waits for the next data packet. Here is the relevant code:

```
                else if (b == 'a')
                {
                        memcpy(&dacpkt.seqNum, buffer+sizeof(char), sizeof(int));
                        dacpkt.seqNum = ntohl(dacpkt.seqNum);           // convert from network to host data
                        datapkt.pktLen = 1017;
                        if (dacpkt.seqNum == datapkt.seqNum)
                        {
                                ++seq;
                                dacpkt.t = b;

                                datapkt.seqNum = seq;
                                fread(datapkt.data, datapkt.pktLen, 1, filereq);

                                memcpy(buffer, &datapkt.t, sizeof(char));                               // data packet type
                                off = sizeof(char);
                                datapkt.seqNum = htonl(datapkt.seqNum);
                                memcpy(buffer + off, &datapkt.seqNum, sizeof(int));     // data packet sequence#
                                off += sizeof(int);
                                datapkt.pktLen = htons(datapkt.pktLen);
                                memcpy(buffer + off, &datapkt.pktLen, sizeof(short));   // data packet size
                                off += sizeof(short);
                                memcpy(buffer + off, &datapkt.data, 1017);                              // data packet payload
                                n = sendto(sock, buffer, MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &from, fromlen);
                                if (n < 0)
                                        error("sendto");
                        }

                        if(fread(datapkt.data, 1017, 1, filereq) != 1017)       // fread hit the end of the file
                        {
                                ++seq;
                                dacpkt.t = 'c';
                                dacpkt.seqNum = seq;
                                memcpy(buffer, &dacpkt.t, sizeof(char));                        // close packet
                                off = sizeof(char);
                                dacpkt.seqNum = htonl(dacpkt.seqNum);
                                memcpy(buffer + off, &dacpkt.seqNum, sizeof(int));      // close packet sequence#
                                n = sendto(sock, buffer, 5, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &from, fromlen);
                        }

                }
```

dacpkt is the acknowledgement packet that I populate upon deserialization of the char buffer from recvfrom(), and datapkt is the packet I build, then serialize and send. I BELIEVE my issue is in my usage of fread. Here is the receiving code client-side:

```
                        if (b == 'd')
                        {
                                //build the response packet and send
                                memset(buffer, 0, MAX);
                                //populate struct
                                dacpkt.t = 'a';
                                dacpkt.seqNum = htonl(sequence_num);

                                //copy to buffer
                                memcpy(buffer, &dacpkt.t, sizeof(char));
                                off = sizeof(char);
                                memcpy(buffer + off, &dacpkt.seqNum, sizeof(int));

                                //send the ACK
                                n = sendto(sock, buffer, MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, length);
                                if (n < 0)
                                        error("sendto");

                                //receive as well before exiting while loop
                                memset(buffer, 0, MAX);
                                n = recvfrom(sock, buffer, MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);
                                if (n < 0)
                                        error("recvfrom");

                                datapkt.t = buffer[0];
                                off = sizeof(char);
                                memcpy(&datapkt.seqNum, buffer + off, sizeof(int));
                                datapkt.seqNum = ntohl(datapkt.seqNum);
                                off += sizeof(int);
                                memcpy(&datapkt.pktLen, buffer + off, sizeof(short));
                                datapkt.pktLen = ntohl(datapkt.pktLen);
                                off += sizeof(short);
                                strcat(datapkt.data, buffer + off);

                                //ensures we are receiving the next packet
                                if (datapkt.seqNum = (sequence_num + 1))
                                {
                                        n = fputs(datapkt.data, newfile); //we need buffer to be the exact size
                                        if (n < 0)
                                                error("writing to file");

                                        sequence_num = datapkt.seqNum;
                                }

                        }

                        fclose(newfile);
                }
                //post-receiving the file!
                memset(buffer, 0, MAX);
                dacpkt.t = 'c';
                dacpkt.seqNum = htonl(sequence_num);
                memcpy(buffer, &dacpkt.t, sizeof(char));
                memcpy(buffer + 1, &dacpkt.seqNum, sizeof(int));
                //send the ACK
                n = sendto(sock, buffer, MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, length);
                if (n < 0)
                        error("sendto");
```

I am sorry if the information I gave is a bit ambiguous, but I am fairly certain my issues lie in my reading/writing to file. For instance, I ran the program trying to transfer a text file with the alphabet characters (a-z) on each line, on 600 lines. Original file was 16200 bytes, whereas the new file created by the sending data is only 3069 bytes. The new file is only 113 lines, and random bytes appear throughout like this:

```
 36 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 37 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 38 abcdefghijklmnopqr8ze$ü^?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 39 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and notably, at the end of the file:

```
111 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
112 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
113 abcdefghi8ze$ü^?
```

I think I do not understand how fread() works, in regards to how to tell when to end the file transfer. If anyone has ideas on how I could implement this better, I'm all ears. All I want to do, is send data in one kb packets at a time, until I reach end of file, at which point, I send this final, partial packet, then send a signal to close the client.

Answer (score 0):

Two things strike immediately.

- `fread` returns the *number of items* it read. `fread(datapkt.data, 1017, 1, filereq)` tries to read *one* item of size 1017. There is no chance this call would ever return 1017. It may only return 0 or 1. The test

  ```
      if (fread(....) != 1017)
  ```

  always fails. However, 1017 bytes has been read, and due to the test failure, are discarded. That explains a huge data loss.

  Swap the order of parameters, check how may 1-byte items has been read:

  ```
      size_t bytes = fread(datapkt.data, 1, 1017, filereq);
  ```

  and use this `bytes` as a size of the payload. `bytes < 1017` likely to indicate the end of file. To be sure, call `feof` and `ferror`.
- The server flow:

  ```
      if (dacpkt.seqNum == datapkt.seqNum) {
          ....
          fread(...);
          ....
      }
      if (fread(....) != 1017) {
          ....
      }
  ```

  means that there are *two* calls to `fread` once `seqNum` matches, and a one call if it doesn't. I can't really follow the data flow, but it does feel strange. Server shall not go ahead and send new `seqNum` until ack is received.

  In any case, it shall not blindly send `MAX` bytes. The first `fread` also must check how many bytes it got, and fix the sizes in `memcpy` and `sendto` accordingly.

---

To _detect EOF and read the data at the same time`, try something like

```
    size_t bytes = fread(datapkt.data, 1, 1017, filereq);
    if (bytes == 0 && feof(filereq)) {
        handle_end_of_file();
    } else {
        memcpy(memcpy(buffer + off, &datapkt.data, bytes);
        send_the_packet();
    }
```

Comment: I see what you are saying with the 1017 issue. I was under the (wrong) impression that fread returns the bytes read. As for the other issue, I had a underlying bad feeling about that (if fread) line. What I am attempting to do, in English, is send a packet with 1017 bytes + some header information in a 1024 size char buffer. SeqNum is iterated server side, as I plan to implement a timer that detects packet drop. Basically if client is awaiting seNum 5, it shall not accept 4 (already have it) or 6 (skipped one, packet was dropped).  My question: how to detect EOF with only one fread call?

Comment: To elaborate^ I meant, detect EOF and read the data at the same time, instead of using two calls to fileread()